# Can you run R code on a .md file?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I'm new to R, so this might be a stupid question but I'd appreciate any help.

Can you execute code on a .md file? I know that you can include code, but it doesn't show the output like it does in a .Rmd file. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `.md`files contain text and format tags while `.Rmd` contains also R code and is processed by R